# Find the (row,column) locations of all matches to a substring in large dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, string-matching

Find the (row,column) locations of all matches containing the substring 'en' in large dataset.

1. Dataset has over 100 cols & 1 Million rows
2. Originally don't know whether it exist or not

Example dataset:

```
#Dataset call df
       col_1 col_2 col_3
    1    101  10n1 cb101
    2 ed10en    dn   101
    3    101   NA  1e01
    4    101 r1en1   ""
    5   en10   101 en5en
```

Result like : 1st match is (2,1) , 2nd match is (5,1), 3rd match is (4,2) , 4th match is (5,3) is what expected the solution can provide.

```
>"2,1","5,1","4,2","5,3"
```

or any vectorizable expression.

1. ※`which(df == "en",arr.ind = T)` can't find substring matches, and doesn't work for character.
2. ※`grep("en",df[1:ncol(df)])` cannot return ROW index
3. ※`for (i in 1:ncol(df)){print(grep("en",df[i]))}` Index of COL is not visualized and cannot return the index of SECOND ENCOUNTER in same col.
4. Function in Excel: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> --Find > "Find All" is more like the
   expected solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps!

```
l <- lapply(colnames(df), function(x) grep("en", df[,x]))
final_result <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(l), function(i) paste(l[[i]], i, sep = ",")))
final_result
```

Output is:

```
[1] "2,1" "5,1" "4,2" "5,3"
```

Sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(col_1 = c("101", "ed10en", "101", "101", "en10"
), col_2 = c("10n1", "dn", NA, "r1en1", "101"), col_3 = c("cb101", 
"101", "1e01", "", "en5en")), .Names = c("col_1", "col_2", "col_3"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
))
```

Comment: Prefect .  I am still a beginner that haven't been use " function(x) ". Are there any easy way to understand this code ? --`lapply(seq_along(l), function(i) paste(l[[i]], i, sep = ","))` --- especially when paste("x","d", sep =" , ") = 
" x , d" , then , whats the middle " i " in paste() argument functioning?

Comment: If you print `str(l)` (i.e. 1st `lapply` result) then you can see that it's a "list of 3". It is of size "3" because `function(x)` applied on 3 columns of `df`. Now coming back to your question - `l[[i]]` (i.e. ith element of list `l`) output the row index and `i` gives column index of `df` (you can print `l` to confirm it). When you apply `paste` on top of these combination you get the desired result.

Comment: Thankyou. double [[]] bracket return EVERY elements and the second argument of paste add i itself to every element with them .

Comment: Is there a way to convert the output to a table of rows and columns? Thank you!

Comment: @tom could you be more specific about your desired output? Do you simply want to replace the content of original table with True/ False based on substring's presence or absence respectively?

Answer (score 3):

```r
reprex::reprex_info()
#> Created by the reprex package v0.1.1.9000 on 2018-02-10
```

You can use `grepl` coupled with some trickery to get the result as row
and column indices rather than a vector index that you get from `grep`.

```r
df <- read.table(
header = T, text = '
     col_1 col_2 col_3
       101  10n1 cb101
    ed10en    dn   101
       101    NA  1e01
       101 r1en1    ""
      en10   101 en5en')

x <- as.matrix(df)
i <- grepl("en", x)    # logical vector of length = nrow(x) * ncol(x)
i
#>  [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#> [12] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

dim(i) <- dim(x)       # coerce to matrix with same dimensions as x
i
#>       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
#> [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#> [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [4,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#> [5,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

which(i, arr.ind = T)  # check which are TRUE and report as row, col
#>      row col
#> [1,]   2   1
#> [2,]   5   1
#> [3,]   4   2
#> [4,]   5   3
```

Another approach could be to just use `grep`, combined with some modular
arithmetic to figure out the row and column positions, given the
dimensions of your data, and using the fact that matrices in R are basically
column vectors wrapped at the number of rows:

```r
i <- grep("en", x)
i
#> [1]  2  5  9 15

row <- 1 + (i - 1) %% nrow(x)   # number of positions outside full columns
col <- 1 + (i - 1) %/% nrow(x)  # number of full columns before position i

cbind(row, col)
#>      row col
#> [1,]   2   1
#> [2,]   5   1
#> [3,]   4   2
#> [4,]   5   3
```

It feels like the latter approach would be more efficient given large data, since you can avoid the creation of a large intermediate logical vector.

Comment: Obviously an elegant approach . Can you explain how the mathematical operating in both row <- 1 + (i - 1) %% nrow(x) and  col <- 1 + (i - 1) %/% nrow(x) work ?  I can only roughly understand %% and %/% definition but not clear for what STEP in the code done .

Comment: [Matrices in R are atomic vectors with a dimension attribute.](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/data-structures.html#matrices-and-arrays) They are filled column-wise, meaning that if a position on the vector is larger than the number of rows, it "goes over" to the next column. We can use [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers), and divide vector positions with the number of rows in the matrix, to find the quotient (`%/%`) and remainder (`%%`) that give us the column and row indices, respectively.

Comment: The whole `1 + (i - 1)` thing is needed because R starts indexing from 1 rather than `0`. With indices starting from `0` we could just have `row <- i %% nrow(x)` and `col <- i %/% nrow(x)`.

Comment: Thank you very much Mikko. i get it now !